# Build from command line in Codegear 2009 IDE

Tags: makefile, c++builder

Is it possible to automagically generate a MAKEFILE from the Codegear 2009 IDE? Or build a project from the command line?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, but depending on your objective, you may be able to do what you want. If you simply want to do a build from a command line, this is possible. Because CB2009 uses msbuild, you can drive a build which uses all the same options and settings as an IDE build. There is a rsvars.bat file which sets all the environment variables you need and a shortcut to this batch file installed in the start menu called "RAD Studio Command Prompt" Once those are set, you can then call:

> `msbuild yourProjectFile.cbproj`

This can then be integrated into a make system, continuous integration tool, or other automation.