# Set build configuration for command line build in Codegear 2009 IDE

Tags: c++builder

This is a follow up [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5877414/build-from-command-line-in-codegear-2009-ide).  Is it possible to set the build configuration for a command line build in Codegear 2009?

For example:

```
msbuild /property:BuildConfiguration=Release workspaceX.groupproj
```

Comment: Just found answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4287566/compiling-c-builder-project-on-command-line

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes.  In fact you're very close with your example.  Use `/p:Configuration="Name"`:

```
msbuild YourProj.cbproj /p:Configuration="Release Build"
```

It is `Configuration="Name"` for a C++Builder project, and `config="Name"` for a Delphi project, which you'll need to be aware of if your project group mixes Delphi and C++Builder projects.  (I don't know why this is, but there you go. You would not believe how long that took to figure out.  Edit: according to a comment, 'config' works in 2009.  I can only state that for certain it did not work for us in 2010.)

You can also use `/t:` to specify a target, such as cleaning, building or making your project; `/verbosity` to set an output level ('`quiet`' is the closest that mimics the old C++Builder 6 compiler output without writing a custom MSBuild logger); and other switches which you can see if you type `msbuild /?` at a command line.  You can end up with something like this:

```
msbuild YourProj.cbproj /p:Configuration="Release Build" /t:Make /verbosity:quiet /nologo
```

You'll need to include a line like this in your build script for each project in your project group.  <strike>As far as I'm aware, you can't build or make a project group itself as a whole from the command line.</strike>

Comment: Hi David, in 2009 you can msbuild the .groupproj file. Also, /p:config="Release" worked for me when building a groupproj file with C++ projects.